# Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Tags: typescript, oop

I am trying create classes with TypeScript. But, when i execute the function. Console said `Cannot read property 'client' of undefined` its mean `this` is undefined. But, why?

Code:

```
import type { Request, Response } from "express";
import type { IRoute } from "../interfaces";
import type RaznarTicketClient from "../structures/RaznarClient";

export default class HomeRoute implements IRoute {
    readonly name = "/";
    constructor(public client: RaznarTicketClient) {}
    public async exec(_: Request,res: Response) {
        const tickets = await this.client.ticket.getTickets();
        return res.json(tickets);
    }
}
```

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined`

Comment: maybe its coming the `getTickets()`?

Comment: How do you invoke `exec` method? It souns like you are invoking it without binding `this`. like eg. `mouseClick.subscribe(this.exec)` while it must be `mouseClick.subscribe(this.exec.bind(this))`

Comment: solved, I forgot to bind the method.